# Form Regex that finds pattern within a repeating decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing, qunit

How can I form a regular expression that match the unique numbers that repeat in a repeating decimals?

Currently my regular expressions is the following.

```
var re = /(?:[^\.]+\.\d*)(\d+)+(?:\1)$/;
```

Example:

```
// Pass
deepEqual( func(1/111), [ "0.009009009009009009", "009" ] );

// Fails, since func(11/111) returns [ "0.099099099099099", "9" ]
deepEqual( func(11/111), [ "0.099099099099099", "099" ] );
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9dGsw/

Here's my code.

```
// Goal: Find the pattern within repeating decimals.
// Problem from: Ratio.js <https://github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js>

var func = function( val ){
    var re = /(?:[^\.]+\.\d*)(\d+)+(?:\1)$/;
    var match = re.exec( val );
    if( !match ){
        val = (val||"").toString().replace( /\d$/, '' );
        match = re.exec( val );
    }
    return match;
};
test("find repeating decimals.", function() {
    deepEqual( func(1), null );
    deepEqual( func(1/10), null );
    deepEqual( func(1/111), [ "0.009009009009009009", "009" ] );

    // This test case fails...
    deepEqual( func(11/111), [ "0.099099099099099", "099" ], 
        "What's wrong with re in func()?" );

    deepEqual( func(100/111), [ "0.9009009009009009", "009"] );
    deepEqual( func(1/3), [ "0.3333333333333333", "3"]);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Regex to capture repeating part of decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363390/javascript-regex-to-capture-repeating-part-of-decimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I somewhat solved my own problem by taking Joel's advice.

The problem was that the regular expression section, `(\d+)+(?:\1)$`, was matching the pattern closest to the end of the string, which made it return "9", instead of "099" for the string "0.099099099099099".

The way I overcame this problem was by setting the match length to 2 or greater, like so.

`(\d{2,})+(?:\1)$`,

and filtering the result with `/^(\d+)(?:\1)$/`, incase that a pattern is stuck inside a pattern.

Here's the code that passes all my test cases.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9dGsw/1/

```
var func = function( val ){
    val = (val || "").toString();
    var RE_PatternInRepeatDec = /(?:[^\.]+\.\d*)(\d{2,})+(?:\1)$/, 
        RE_RepeatingNums = /^(\d+)(?:\1)$/,
        match = RE_PatternInRepeatDec.exec( val );

    if( !match ){
        // Try again but take off last digit incase of precision error.
        val = val.replace( /\d$/, '' );
        match = RE_PatternInRepeatDec.exec( val );
    }
    if( match && 1 < match.length ){
        // Reset the match[1] if there is a pattern inside the matched pattern.
       match[1] = RE_RepeatingNums.test(match[1]) ? RE_RepeatingNums.exec(match[1])[1] : match[1];
    }
    return match;
};
```

Thank you for everyone that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `var re = /^(?:\d*)\.(\d{1,3})(?:\1)+$/`

I have defined the min/max length with {min,max} of the repeating decimal because otherwise 009009009 would match in the first test case as well. Maybe it is still not the final solution, but at least a hint.

Comment: it would be better to escape the dot to make your intent to match a dot (and not anything) explicit