# JavaScript Regex to capture repeating part of decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for the best way to take an arbitrary number with potentially repeating decimal part, and discover the repeating part (if present).

Ultimately, I need to decorate the number with overline notation (either with css text-decoration or MathML mline), so I need to know the index of where the repetition begins also.

So I need regex that will get me (or can be used in an algorithm to get) the following results:

```
1.333 // result: {"pattern": 3, index: 0}
1.5444 // result: {"pattern": 4, index: 1}
1.123123 // result: {"pattern": 123, index: 0}
1.5432121212 // result: {"pattern": 12, index: 4}
1.321 // result: null
1.44212 // result: null
```

Additional Example (from comments):

```
1.3333 // result: { "pattern": 3, index: 0}
```

Comment: You should add at least one additional case to your list of examples: `1.3333 // result: { "pattern": 3, index: 0}` because a lot of the answers below are failing on this case. (I'm assuming you want a general solution and not just one that will work for *some* numbers.)

Comment: Do you care that this approach will incorrectly claim that the decimal representations of non-repeating fractions (like 133/100 - exactly 1.33) are repeating?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: A *really* good point.

Comment: How would a number like 5/3 be represented? `1.66666667`?

Comment: @AndrewMedico - No, its really just a display function, so if the client passes in a number to it, they know what they are getting back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function getRepetend(num) {
    var m = (num+'').match(/\.(\d*?)(\d+?)\2+$/);
    return m && {pattern: +m[2], index: m[1].length};
}
```

It works like this:

- First, convert the number to string in order to be able to use regular expressions.
- Then, match this regex: `/\.(\d*?)(\d+)\2+$/`:

  - `\.` matches the decimal dot.
  - `(\d*?)` matches the digits between the decimal dot and the repetend, and captures the result into backreference number 1.
  - `(\d+?)` matches the repetend, and captures it into backreference number 2.
  - `\2+` matches repetitions of the repetend.
  - `$` matches end of string.
- Finally, if the match is `null` (i.e. there is no match), return `null`.
- Otherwise, return an object that contains the repetend (backreference 2) converted to number, and the number of digits between the dot and the repetend (backreference 1).

Comment: Thanks Oriol, this really got me started on the right track!

Comment: That's the way to do it!

Comment: Nice one.......

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
(\d+?)\1+$
```

http://regex101.com/r/eX8eC3/3

It matched some number of digits and then uses a backreference to try and match the same set immediately afterwards 1 or more times. It's anchored at the end of the string because otherwise it'll be tripped up by, for example:

```
1.5432121212
```

It would see the `21` repeating instead of the `12`.

Adding `?` to the first group to make it *non-greedy* should fix the problem with `1.3333` as raised by Louis.

Comment: Yea, you'd definitely need the anchor.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Agreed. After writing that I immediately noticed the problem with the `1.5432121212` example.

Comment: Very clever to word backwards!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex with [`RexExp#exec` and use `result.index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) in the resulting object:

```
var re = /(\d+)\1$/;
var s = '.5439876543212211211';

var result = re.exec( s );
console.log ( result.index );
//=> 14

console.log ( result[1] );
//=> 211
```

#### [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9ns0kn1/1/)

Comment: @Louis: Matched part is `result[1]`

Comment: @anubhava: It's wrong because it needs to capture repeating digits from the *end* of the string. I.e. it should capture `3` in `1.3333`, but nothing in `1.3332` because `1.3332` isn't [recurring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).

Comment: @MattBurland: Thanks for your comment. Somehow I overlooked **ending** part in the question. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+)(?:\1)+$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/10

Comment: Fails when the input is `1.3333` (with 4 digits rather than 3). It results in `33` rather than `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepeted answer is OKish as per the given examples in the question are concerned. However if one day you find yourself here what you probably need is exactly what the topic says.

### JavaScript Regex to capture repeating part of decimal

So you have the floating part of a string and you want to know if it is repeating or not. The accepted answer fails in practice. You can never guarantee that the string ends when the repeating part ends. Most of the time the string ends with a portion of the repeating part or sometimes *thanks* to the double precision errors jumps to irrelevant figures towards the end. So my suggestion is

```
/(\d+)\1+(?=\d*$)/g
```

Now this is not a silver bullet. It's helpful but won't protect you from vampires like `3.1941070707811985` which happens to have no repetend at all. In order to feel it you have to develop deeper mechanisms. However in most cases it's just fine in percieving the repend like in

```
3.1941070707811985   // 07 which is wrong so prove it later
7.16666666810468     // 666 but reduce it to 6 later
3.00000000000001     // 000000 but reduce it to "" later
0.008928571428571428 // 285714 just fine, do nothing
```

It is not an easy task to find if the floating part of a decimal has repetends or not in this environment. Most possibly you need to do further processing on the given string and the result of the regex for futher reduction / decision.