# Is it possible to determine if a number is recursive in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'd like 1/3 (which equals `0.33333` recurring) to return true and 1/8 (which equals `0.125` non-recurring) to be false.

Something like `=ISRECURRING(A1)` which returns a boolean.

The reason for this is that I want to highlight cells that have had rounding applied to them.

Comment: Are those the actual formulas you have used?

Comment: I think you could check =LEN(1/3).. If it is crossing 16 then it is recurring. I don't know exactly how many decimals allowed in excel, may be 15. So, if the number is in A1, then you can check LEN(A1-INT(A1))

Comment: @Naresh how can you say that crossing 16 makes it recurring?

Comment: OP want to check it for numbers rounded. I don't think anyone would want to keep 16 decimals. Also, excel will not give you more decimal numbers on a worksheet (May be in VBA with string variable). So why not assume 16 decimal places is a recurring number in this case?

Comment: Agreed in this scenario :)

Comment: PI is >16 decimals but the fractional part is not recurring.

Comment: You really have two different questions, not related. 1) Is a decimal recurring? 2) Has rounding been applied to the cell?  And it seems as if question 2 is what you are interested in, but why?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld good point - simply knowing if it has been rounded will do. The reason is I'm modelling an underlying asset that has a digital representation on top (tokens). The underlying has a dollar value which changes, so to take the token and display a dollar amount will cause some rounding. I want to highlight this in the spreadsheet as the total value of the underlying and the tokens must be exactly the same.

Comment: To add to this, basically I want to change my modelling and see all the "red" rounded cells no longer be red (or indeed rounded) to be reasonably sure the new model works. Of course it will then require more investigation but that's the general idea.... maybe I'm approaching a maths problem with a hammer :)

Comment: Values in cells can be rounded for many reasons -- repeating decimals, infinite decimals, numbers with decimals > Excel precision, explicit rounding with the `ROUND` function or similar, issues with representing certain decimal numbers in binary (which also intersects with how MS handles those kinds of numbers), etc.  You may need to re-think your issue.

Comment: Perhaps something like `num - round(num,14) <> 0` might provide a start.

Comment: So I'm not using the `ROUND` function, but yes all the other incidents of rounding I'd want flagged. I understand your solution with the ROUND function, thank you, that's definitely useful.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer, if you found a solution that works for your case.

Comment: Good point, done. Credit to @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [@Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld).

`=A1-ROUND(A1,14) <> 0` works a treat. Where A1 is the number in question.

I can't guarantee that every rounded number works but it appears to work on all the examples I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a JavaScript function to check that and use it in your sheet as an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project (credits to [Larry Battle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527776/larry-battle), whose [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803250) this function is based on):

```js
function ISRECURRING(num) {
  num = (num || "").toString().replace(/\d$/, '');
  var RE_PatternInRepeatDec = /(?:[^\.]+\.\d*)(\d{2,})+(?:\1)$/;
  return RE_PatternInRepeatDec.exec(num) ? true : false;
};
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function as if you were using a regular sheets formula. You just have to provide the appropriate range as an argument, as you can see here:

[image]

#### Note:

- As @Ron Rosenfeld noted in a comment below, this function will not work for very long repetends (e.g. `1/97`). This is due to the precision limit that spreadsheets have (15 digits, as far as I know). Because of this, repetends longer than 7 digits won't be detected.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: There seems to be some limitations to your function. For example `1/97` produces a repeating decimal, but your function returns `FALSE` *(96 repeating digits)*

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for pointing that out! Since neither spreadsheets nor JavaScript can handle so many digits, I guess this was to be expected. I seriously doubt there is a way to detect such long repetends.

Comment: I think a good algorithm, assuming the fraction to be tested is entered as a text string, would be to 1) Reduce the fraction to it's simplest form 2) Factor the denominator into its primes. 3) If all of the prime factors are `2` or `5`, then it is NOT a repeating decimal; otherwise it is.